# Why does the BRAT diet recommend toast instead plain bread?

Tags: diet, diarrhea

The BRAT diet is commonly used when a patient has diarrhea:

> [Cleaveland Clinic: What To Eat When You Have Diarrhea](https://health.clevelandclinic.org/what-to-eat-when-you-have-diarrhea/)
>
> Your food and drink choices can help ease diarrhea symptoms and get
> you back to feeling normal.
>
> - Bananas. Starch in the fruit can help absorb water in your colon, which works to firm up your stool. Plus, it’s rich in potassium, a key
>   electrolyte you’re losing with diarrhea.
> - Rice. Select white rice over brown rice in this case, as it’s easier on your stomach.
> - Applesauce. Look to grab unsweetened applesauce to cut down on sugar.
> - **Toast.** Try to use the more easily digestible white bread instead of whole grain bread.

---

Is there something more effective about toast instead of plain bread? Or is toast just more appetizing?

Comment: Congratulations on posting the first question I've ever seen that meets this site's requirements for diet and nutrition questions.

Comment: I think simply more appetizing and easily digestible. Anecdote: my microbiologist parent used to feed us burned toast for vomiting as the charcoal could absorb toxins inducing the vomiting.

Comment: I tried searching for early recommendations of the BRAT diet to see why; no go. According to several sources, it was first proposed in 1926. Frankly, I think it was just to create a catchy mnemonic, as some sources also say bread/saltines. **It is no longer recommended.** (Personally I used to recommended lightly buttered toast, as the gut needed fat to regenerate injured cells.)